Noob question - Jupyter Lab - no login / no account?
thanks for all the help in getting a noob like me onboarded.
I was trying to get some coding done on my work laptop, and it's impossible to install anything without admin privileges, so I was looking at Jupyter Labs as a web-based platform for creating and saving python projects. The problem is that there appears to be no account-based access for Jupyter Labs...no login or anything. Am I supposed to save all my work on an online repository? Or am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

" so I was looking at Jupyter Labs as a web-based platform. The problem is that there appears to be no account-based access for Jupyter Labs...no login or anything" Where do you mean specifically? A lot of offerings have accounts. And if you get a generic cloud machine and set it up yourself, it definitely has login. (Old example of that is here, but YMMV because details change with time.) Please be specific and include references.

I will add though that anything you make that is valuable is best downloaded & kept as .ipynb stored on your local machine. This way if your server or virtual machine goes kablooie or you lose access at least you have that to move elsewhere. And if you are for now still fine without login/account/setting up your own machines for just getting started, see here for more guidance and maybe resources you haven't seen before for wading in to writing Jupyter notebooks.

Even if you do not have admin privilege on your PC, you can install packages with pip --user. If need be you can even download the package first, move it to your PC and then install it offline.

JupyterLab functions like an IDE (for Jupyter notebooks). Try hosted Jupyter services (Google Colab or Microsoft Azure Notebooks), where they come with cloud storage.

Google Colab is a very different beast. You'd be better off and have more flexibility using vanilla Jupyter installed on a server or virtual machine you access. I cannot comment on Azure's felxibility as I haven't tried it in a long time.

Depends on OP's needs. Considering that they have called themselves new, something like Google Colab is a great starting point - installation free, resource free (great if ML related, e.g.), google drive integration to save/load, comes with pre-installed libraries, and if they need it, real-time collaboration support.
